# noremap in .vimrc for YouCompleteMe does not work

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, youcompleteme

```
noremap <leader>gdf :YcmCompleter\ GoToDefinition<cr>
noremap <leader>gdc :YcmCompleter\ GoToDeClaration<cr>
noremap <leader>gi :YcmCompleter\ GoToInclude<cr>
noremap <leader>gs :YcmCompleter\ GoToSymbol<cr>
noremap <leader>gt :YcmCompleter\ GoToType<cr>
noremap <leader>gr :YcmCompleter\ GoToReferences<cr>
```

None of them works. I get this error message:

```
ValueError: Supported commands are:
GetDoc
GetType
GoTo
```

I ran `python3 install.py --clangd-completer`. The command `:YcmCompleter GoToInclude` does work in a c source file. But the keymap I set does not work. So I think it is not due to an incomplete installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `noremap <leader>gdf :YcmCompleter GoToDefinition<cr>`, no backslash.